# Regular expression using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Here's is the scenario, i have these lines mentioned below i wanted to extract only the middle character in between two dots.

```
 "scvmm.new.resources" --> This after an regular expression match should return only "new"
 "sc.new1.rerces" --> This after an regular expression match should return only "new1"
```

What my basic requirement was to exract anything between two dots anything can come in prefix and suffix

```
 (.*).<required code>.(.*)
```

Could anyone please help me out??

Comment: i guess a typo error :), have corrected it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that without using regex. Split the string on '.' and grab the middle element:

```
PS> "scvmm.new.resources".Split('.')[1]
new
```

Comment: Brilliant shay, i never even thought about this :), Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Or this

```
'scvmm.new.resources' -replace '.*\.(.*)\..*', '$1'
```

Comment: Like the replace, I do it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 ([regex]::Match("scvmm.new1.resources", '(?<=\.)([^\.]*)(?=\.)' )).value
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need regular expressions for such a trivial substring extraction. Like Shay's `Split('.')` one can use `IndexOf()` for similar effect like so,

```
$s = "scvmm.new.resources"
$l = $s.IndexOf(".")+1
$r = $s.IndexOf(".", $l)
$s.Substring($l, $r-$l) # Prints new

$s = "sc.new1.rerces"
$l = $s.IndexOf(".")+1
$r = $s.IndexOf(".", $l)
$s.Substring($l, $r-$l) # Prints new1
```

This looks the first occurence of a dot. Then it looks for first occurense of a dot after the first hit. Then it extracts the characters between the two locations. This is useful in, say, scenarios in which the separation characters are not the same (though the `Split()` way would work in many cases too).